# Add MPart in all MPerspective in eclipse Juno

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-juno

I'm creating one RCP in Eclipse 4.2. In my RCP I have 3 perspective.
I'm creating one part at run-time and adding it in perspective like following.

```
@Inject
EPartService partService;
@Inject
MApplication application;    
...

Mpart part = .... ;    
...

List<MPartStack> stacks = modelService.findElements(application, null, MPartStack.class, null);
stacks.get(0).getChildren().add(part);
partService.showPart(part, PartState.ACTIVATE);
```

But the problem is its added view in current opened perspective so if you switch perspective to other this view will not be shown there which is correct because I'm just add it to 1st stack.
**But  My requirement** is it should be added in every perspective so if it switch to other perspective it should be there.

I'm getting List of MPerspective like following:

```
List<MPerspective> mPerspective = modelService.findElements(application, null, MPerspective.class, null);
```

**But don't know how to add it.**

So how to add Part in each perspective.?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse 3.x there was the concept of [StickyViews](http://eclipseo.blogspot.de/2007/08/sticky-views.html), and you might still be able to use it via the compatibility layer.
However, the Eclipse 4 application model is much more flexible, and there should be several ways you can add such a 'sticky' MPart.

In the screenshot below you can see that in your Application.e4xmi you can have several Perspective Stacks, and even Mparts or MPartStacks on the same level. In your example above you can simply add the MPart to a second MPartStack that is on the same level in the application model as your Perspective Stack:

```
stacks.get(1).getChildren().add(part);
```

[image: Application.e4xmi]